# Overriding magento cms controller for noRoute action

Tags: magento, controller

I'm looking for example of overriding cms controller for noRoute action. I'm trying to make my 404 page send me an email when it happens.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/magento-cms-controller-override-noroute-method-modify/) and did everything exactly as written but nothing happens.

I googled some more and [found this](http://www.spinonesolutions.com/2010/03/magento-controller-override/) which also doesen't work for me.

My Magento version is 1.5.0.0-rc1.

Could anyone give me any link to some tutorial or example code? Thank you very much!

Comment: first : don't use release candidate or beta software and what if 404 was spammed 10000 or 100000 times ?

Comment: We will use dedicated email for this 404 error. Email is meant for notification about url where customer landed - so we can make .htaccess rewrite rules for old urls.

Is there any other, better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mXperts skuroute extension - get it and edit the controller.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mxperts/extension/1749/mxperts-skuroute

Answer (score 3):

I've did some try/error research and managed to create my module. After a lot of search I found that Magento uses custom No-route controller for 404 pages (this page is GOLD: http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages). This can be set as following:

Under "System -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Pages" I've changed the setting for Default No-route URL which now points to my custom made controller.

I've basically copied contents from the existing CMS IndexController and added my own logic (sending email and showing search form). That's it, it works form me.

Thanks to everyone.