# Whats the best way to capture 404s in Magento

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404

I'm writing a custom Magento module to handle 404 URLs of the web site to fulfill some marketing requirements.
I'm wondering what would be the best way to capture the 404s and pass those through my module before it get to the Apache 404 page?

I have scene few ways of people doing it, but not specific to Magento though. So please feel free to provide your expert advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found another easy way of doing it, 
Go to `Admin > System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages`, then change the value for "Default No-route URL" to whatever your modules controller action e.g `myweb\new404manager\index`

This way when a 404 is occur it will point to the controller action defined under this field.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by rewrite the  cms controller for noRoute

Take a look @

[Overriding magento cms controller for noRoute action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737500/overriding-magento-cms-controller-for-noroute-action)

http://magento4u.wordpress.com/tag/cms-noroute-redirection/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/tutorial-integrating-3rd-party-cms-content-within-magento/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a method specific to your CMS. Just add to your .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /some_php_script.php
```

Or this, with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ some_php_script.php/$1
```

The latter has the advantage of letting you access POST data. This php script is in charge to connect to your CMS code somehow.

You should be able to get the original url with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. This script is in charge of replying the status, with either `200 OK` or `404 Not Found`, using the [header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function

**Edit**: Turns out that magento already does this (all the non-static urls are routed to index.php). I'm not familiar enough with the CMS, but it seems it displays a page with identifier "no-route", so hopefully you can replace the contents of this page with something you need (the relevant code is the `Mage_Cms_Model_Page` class, `NOROUTE_PAGE_ID`, and the `noRoutePage()` function). `grep -r` is your friend when trying to understand how to deal with code other people wrote :D

Comment: Are you really sure this works with Magento? For PHP scripts that are files on disk, this might work, but AFAIk Magento already uses pretty URLs, so you need to have that inside Magento, not inside Apache.

Comment: Yeah I'm dumb, didn't consider that. Looks like now I have no choice but to research what OP wants to do :D

Comment: No, that is actually the job of the OP - to do the research. I give you an upvote instead just for the feedback :) It's not that it answers this question, but it answers a more general question :)

Comment: Wait, you mean I'm not here to do work for other people in exchange for reputation points? Either way, updating the answer with what I found from a quick grep.

Comment: Actually I did my reaseach as well and found out the noRouteAction in CMS indexController does the job in Magento, Thanx to xdebug ;). Thinking of writing a observer to listen to this event, this is still under research though :). Anyway thank you very much on your valuable feedback

Comment: This will only work for 404's in the skin, media or js directories. For normal requests Magento captures the 404.